# Getting window is not defined on ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fbjs

I am getting the error: `"ReferenceError: window is not defined"` on React.

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Header.css';
import withStyles from '../../decorators/withStyles';
import Link from '../../utils/Link';
import SignInMenu from './SignInMenu';
import UserMenu from './UserMenu';
import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import { canUseDOM } from 'fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment';

@withStyles(styles)
class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    return {
      windowWidth: 0,
      windowHeight: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
      windowHeight: window.innerHeight
    });
  }

  render() {
     let windowWidth = this.state.windowWidth;
     let windowHeight = this.state.windowHeight;

     if (windowWidth < 1000) {
       let header = (<div>mobile</div>);
     }  else {
       let header = (<div>desktop</div>);
    }
  }
```

I am trying to render different views for desktop and mobile and am just starting out with React. I am not sure if I am doing this right, was following some guides online and got stuck here. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you doing server side rendering? Window should always be provided by the browser.

Comment: Yes I am doing server side rendering

Comment: Where is your code actually referencing `window`? Or where does the compiled code do?

Comment: Is there anyway to get the width of the window? what I am trying to achieve here is to render a different component if the page is viewed on a smaller screen and not render certain components in that case. Is there any solution for this when using serverside rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be in your constructor.

```
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        windowWidth: 0,
        windowHeight: 0
      };
    }
```